# Ignore autocomplete suggestion when typing

Tags: notepad++

I know that `TAB` and `ENTER` select the autocomplete word, but what key for ignoring it?

For example, in notepad++ if I previously wrote `student` in a file and now I want to write `stud`, how can I discard the suggestion and simply let the word be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that stud is a word you want to type, you are most likely going to follow that by a space, comma, period, exclaimation point or question mark.

Basically any other keypress other than <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> will discard the autocomplete dialog. If you really want to discard it but not move the cursor, or use the regular function of <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel the autocomplete popup first.